# How can I name a variable automatically by its type in a live template?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, live-templates

Using dagger, Im injecting fields a lot - so I created a live template for declaring an injected variable:

```
@Inject
lateinit var $var$: $TYPE$
```

In Java, a similar live template would automatically fill in **repository** as I specified the type to be `Repository`.

In Kotlin, however - it does not. But Im sure its possible?

Answer (score 4):

**Figured it out! Posting a screenshot as I think that explains it the best.**

[image: Live template variables]

Answer (score 1):

I have a slight variation on this that uses smart completion.  The key thing that evaded me at first was making sure you re-order the variables so the TYPE is before the VAR.  Otherwise the type will be empty.
[image: Spring Live Template Variables]